# Paginator and POST request for SearchForm

Tags: python, django

I've an issue with Paginator in Django, I tried several solution but none is working as I want...

Views

```
def order_list(request)
    form = SearchOrderForm()
    if 'search-order-post' in request.session:
        form = SearchOrderForm(request.session['search-order-post'])
        is_cookie_set = 1

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchOrderForm(request.POST)
        request.session['search-order-post'] = request.POST
        is_cookie_set = 1

    if is_cookie_set == 1:
        if form.is_valid():
            statut = form.cleaned_data['statut']
            clients = form.cleaned_data['clients']
    [...]
    paginator = Paginator(orders, 50)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        orders_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        orders_page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        orders_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {'clients': clients,
               'orders': orders_page,
               'orders_list': orders,
               'paginate': True,
               'form': form,
               }
    return render(request, 'order/list.html', context)
```

When I use Paginator in GET, to go to page 2 for exemple ... I lost all my query :(
Is there any other way ?
form.is_valid() return False when i change page

Comment: Why not use GET instead of POST for your search form data?

Comment: You're right, first I didn't wan't to show all data in adresse bar ... But yes you're right ... But now I've a question ... how can I add ?page=2 for instance instead of replace ?
In my template I've "href="?page=... " but this erase all request by ?page :(

Comment: I finally used : href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&page={{ orders.previous_page_number }}{{ getvars }}" ... If there is another solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change to using GET, you will need to be able to generate the pagination links with the form data and the correct page number. You can use [`QueryDict.urlencode()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode) to generate a querystring from GET data, if you first pop the current page number you can then provide this manually

```
def order_list(request):

    ...

    get_data = request.GET.copy()
    page = get_data.pop('page', None)

    ...

    context = {
        ...,
        'query_string': get_data.urlencode(),
     }
    return render(request, 'order/list.html', context)
```

Template

```
    <a href="?{% if query_string %}{{ query_string }}&{% endif %}page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

Comment: It's almost what I'm looking for ... but when I first load page query_string is empty so  Url for next page si ?&page=2 ... it doesn't work... I'll try to find a way in view or template to user ? or &

Comment: Can add an `if` tag to only render the `&` when there is data I suppose, if it's not too ugly

Comment: I used If query_string in template to use ? or & depend on result ;) Just want to edit ... too late ;) THanks anyway ;) it's work

Answer (score 0):

Solution with GET request :

TEMPLATE

```
{% if paginate %}
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<nav aria-label="...">
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    {% if orders.has_previous %}
        {% if query_string %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{{ query_string }}&page={{ orders.previous_page_number }}{{ getvars }}"><<</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ orders.previous_page_number }}{{ getvars }}"><<</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#"><<</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if orders.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
        {% if query_string %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{{ query_string }}&page={{ orders.number|add:'-5' }}{{ getvars }}">...</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ orders.number|add:'-5' }}{{ getvars }}">...</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in orders.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if orders.number == i %}
            <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link" href="#">{{ i }}</span></li>
        {% elif i > orders.number|add:'-5' and i < orders.number|add:'10' %}
            {% if query_string %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{{ query_string }}&page={{ i }}{{ getvars }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}{{ getvars }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- <span class="current">{{ commandes.number }} / {{ commandes.paginator.num_pages }}</span>-->
    {% if orders.has_next %}
        {% if query_string %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?{{ query_string }}&page={{ orders.next_page_number }}{{ getvars }}">>></a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ orders.next_page_number }}{{ getvars }}">>></a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#">>></a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```

VIEWS

```
paginator = Paginator(orders, 50)
    get_data = request.GET.copy()
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        orders_page = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        orders_page = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        orders_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'orders': orders_page,
               'paginate': True,
               'form': form,
               'formAction': formAction,
               'query_string': get_data.urlencode(),
               }
    return render(request, 'order/list.html', context)
```

Maybe there is a better way ... but actually it's works ;)
I know it's possible with POST and session or cookie ... but I give up for the moment ... Thanks all for. your help